# Как автоматически сортировать директивы Using(C#) в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В Параметрах нашел только это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... ни одна из опций не помогла.

В справке по расширению [FormatDocumentOnSave](https://github.com/Elders/VSE-FormatDocumentOnSave#command), говорится: *можно указать несколько команд через пробел*. По дефолту там установлена одна команда `Edit.FormatDocument`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом 2 вопроса:

- Есть ли возможность в стилях форматирования указать авто-сортировку `using`?
- Или же, как узнать имя команды для `Правка`->`IntelliSense`->`Сортировать директивы using`?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022#apply-code-styles

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Попробовал я эту команду `Analyze.RunDefaultCodeCleanupOnSolution` установить расширению. У меня все зациклилось и VS вылетел. Собственно автор расширения и писал [об ошибке с этой командой](https://github.com/Elders/VSE-FormatDocumentOnSave#codecleanup).

Comment: Как это относится к той документации, что я вам скинул? Там даже ссылка есть на проверенное (наверно) самими Microsoft расширение, которое вообще не связано как-либо с тем, что кидаете вы. Собственно, к чему это было сказано?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ _Как это относится к той документации(c)_ Все верно, в той документации даже картинка с пунктом меню `Analyze and Code Cleanup`. Как я понимаю команда `Analyze.RunDefaultCodeCleanupOnSolution` запускает профиль по умолчанию(в профиле указана сортировка), если запустить ее в командном окне - код форматируется, но расширение вызывает ошибку. То расширение, что ниже в документации, оказалось рабочим. Теперь я в недоумении: почему скачиваний `Format document on Save` больше в 5 раз чем `Code Cleanup On Save`, если оно глючит... А за подсказку использования другого расширения спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Кстати, и `Code Cleanup On Save` глючит. Использует только первый профиль независимо от настроек. При выходе из VS, так же не сохраняет профиль: он всегда устанавливается в `Profile1`.

Comment: Ну, это уже явно не для SO вопрос, а для разработчиков данных плагинов. Официальную документацию я вам скинул, в ней было расширение, работает или нет, я не проверял (на новой студии мб и нет, старые под вопросом). В любом случае, куда копать вы знаете, можете даже свое расширение написать)

Comment: Как по мне, так их вообще сортировать не нужно. Я туда например смотрю 1 раз за всю разработку приложения, когда перед публикацией релиза вычищаю ненужные юзинги. Их там обычно не более 10. Если у вас длинная портянка из юзингов, значит что-то пошло не так и в текущем cs файле слишком много разнофункционального кода. Стоит задуматься об SRP и/или разбитии класса на несколько partial файлов. И ставлю рубль, что вы злоупотребляете регионами, перестаньте, и вы увидите все недостатки кода, на фоне которых сортировка юзингов - вообще не проблема. Регионы - зло и антипаттерн.

Comment: @aepot Если'б руками сортировать, я бы и не задумывался. Но когда один черт использую авто-формат при сохранении, почему не отсортировать, к тому же в профиле стиля устанавливается и очистка лишних using-ов.

Comment: Жмём Ctrl+Q - фокус на окошко поиска. Вводим "sort" - у меня первый пункт Remove and Sort Usings - Ctrl+R, Ctrl+G.

Comment: Tools > Customize > Keyboards. Вводим sort. Находим пункты Edit.RemoveAndSort, Edit.SortUsings.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А я не догадался набрать там sort, набрал Format и плюнул на это безнадежное дело :(